# How can I load multiple nodes of the same 3d model all at once?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm working on an ARKit application where you would walk through a portal and you'd be somewhere else. I purchased a 3d model of an archway to serve as the portal. I took the model in to Blender to flatten it down to one piece, but the texture disappeared and whenever I apply a new texture it only shows up on one portion of the model.

Here is the original model, only modified by changing it to .dae format. however, I can't load arch1, arch2, arch3, etc. without writing the same line over and over

[image]

With this model I'd be writing the same code over and over

```
private func addPortalArch(hitResult: ARHitTestResult) {

            let portalScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Medieval_portal.dae")
            let portalNode = portalScene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "arch1", recursively: true)
```

// I'd be writing this portalNode = portalScene line over and over for each arch.

//I'd also have to get the position for each piece as far as I understand, which I do not know how I'd begin to do that based on where the user taps to place the portal.

```
            portalNode?.position = SCNVector3(hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x, hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y, hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)

            self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(portalNode!)

        }
```

[image: Now, if I've taken the model in to Blender, and I join all the pieces as one, it turns into a basic grayish brownish model and whenever I add textures, it just puts it on the one spot.]

I need the model to be all once piece but still have the same stonework material over the whole of it.

Comment: Upload your portal door model and I will try to help :)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FeRUq7RkMbP25t_OAPH-5xvkpOb_SmS1/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TZ3K5Q906TgLJmTjhQQlKHXhi2c-iHqE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the file you sent, your best bet is to use the model which contains each aspect of the Arch (your 1st picture).

The 1st step (not always necessary but useful) is to convert the `dae` file to an `.scn` file:

[image]

Having done this you then want to create an `Empty Node` to be the Portal Door `RootNode` and make each element of the Portal a child of this e.g:

[image]

You will also need to rotate each `ChildNode`'s (not the PortalRoot) Euler Angle X by -90 (as when you load the model the Portal Door is on it's side):

[image]

Now since you have a single RootNode, there is no need to loop through all the nodes so that is displayed on the screen. You can simple use a function like this:

```
  /// Places The Portal Door 5m Aeay From The Camera
func setupPortalDoor(){

    //1. Get The Portal Scene
    guard let portalScene = SCNScene(named: "portalDoor.scn"),
        //2. Get The Portal Node
        let portalModel = portalScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "PortalRoot", recursively: false) else { return }

    //3. Add To The ARSCNView Root
    augmentedRealityView?.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(portalModel)

    //4. Position It 5m Away From The Camera
    portalModel.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -5)

    /*
     The Portal Is Large So I Suggest Scaling It ^__________*
    */
}
```

If you later wanted to change the portal arch to say marble you can easily do it like so:

```
 for node in portalModel.childNodes{

        node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
 }
```

Hope this helps...